# Classloader issues with Kafka Connector and Remote Executor (Apache Flink)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

When trying to execute a Flink job on a remote cluster, i keep getting the same ClassLoader exception.

```
    org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskException: Cannot load user class: org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer09
ClassLoader info: URL ClassLoader:
Class not resolvable through given classloader.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.getStreamOperator(StreamConfig.java:207)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:223)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:584)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
10/07/2016 06:34:57 Job execution switched to status FAILING.
```

I am packaging my jar using the maven-shade plugin and this class is definetely packaged with the jar, as can be seen when I look inside my jar.

```
$:jar -tf MyJar.jar |grep "org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer"
    org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaConsumer09.class
    org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.class
```

Here's my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>FloorData</finalName>
                        <shadeTestJar>false</shadeTestJar>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>floordata.cli.launcher.FlinkLauncher</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I am configuring my remote environment as follows in my code.  I am not sure if this is correct, but do I need to specify the location of the kafka connector as an argument to createRemoteEnvironment??

```
InetSocketAddress address = parseHostPortAddress((String) configuration.get(FLINK_JOB_MANAGER_ADDRESS));
            StreamExecutionEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment(address.getHostName(), address.getPort());
```

Comment: Which version of Flink are you using?

Comment: My server instance is 1.1.1.
I edited my original post to include my maven deps

Comment: I managed to get it working by first adding both the kafka-connector jars to the lib directory of my flink cluster, plus my application jar file.  I'm looking at ways to automate the build and at present it doesn't seem a trivial exercise to submit jobs to a remote cluster with using the CLI.

Comment: @john Hey, Did you find a solution for that. Using IDE, I had the same problem but using fat jar it's Ok.